# Did I do something stupid by moving my kids car seat with her still in it?

Tags: car-seat

I moved my 2 year olds car seat to my grandparents car for us all to go out.

At the end of the day, she was out cold. I unclipped the seat from ym parents car, with her still in it, and moved it back to mine. I clipped it in and made sure it was as right as possible. I also checked the restraints to make sure they were still right as well.

The car seat is the latch in kind, that attaches to the clamps between the seat and back. Was that something ok or incredibly dumb? I've only done it once, but don't want to do it again if that was bad.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! For a minute I was expecting to read that something bad had happened! Glad I was wrong. :)

Comment: I am still trying to imagine a child that sleeps so soundly that this could even happen. ;)  I wasn't blessed with any that slept that heavy.

Comment: FYI, those "clamps" are called [Isofix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isofix). :-)

Answer (score 9):

> Was that something ok or incredibly dumb?

No it's perfectly fine.

As long as its **firmly attached in the back seat**, per the car seat manufacturer instructions, your good to go.  I did this many times when my children were still the "car seat size".

Answer (score 2):

It is completely fine, as long as proper care is taken:

- Keep the child latched on the seat, using the seat's own belt.
- Mantain a comfortable inclination
- Do not yank, shake, or drop the seat with the child.
- Take special care with the head, as it can tilt back and forth.
- Double check the attachment of the chair to the new vehicle.

But assuming a careful parent, moving the child on the seat is more comfortable for them than taking them off and putting back afterwards. Did this to my son several times, some times even taking them from the parking lot into the apartment sleeping in the chair.

Comment: I'm sure it's good advice to try to avoid it, but isn't the point of car seats that they provide protection against yanks, shakes, drops and head bobbling? ie I'd rather drop a kid in their car seat than drop one sleeping in my arms.

Comment: Just because it protects against, doesn't mean i'm deliberately doing it. It is my (your, their) precious child after all. @notstoreboughtdirt. [jokingly] I'd rather not ever drop my child [/jokingly] - After [coroners want a warning label not to dip your charger into the bathtub](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4322932/Man-32-dies-charging-iPhone-bath.html), maybe no amount of warning is too much.... :/